# Why width: 0 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

In `@media screen and (max-width: 700px)`, I set `aside {width: 0}`, but it doesn't disappear. After resizing, the window remains as null space with `width: 52px`, why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

section {
  display: table-cell;
}

aside {
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;

  /*__transition*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .25s;
}

footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: table-row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  section {
    width: 100%;
  }

  aside {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>HEADER</header>
      <main>
        <section>SECTION</section>
        <aside>ASIDE</aside>
      </main>
      <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use `display: none`?

Comment: then transition doesn't work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `display: none` you can add this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  aside {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: great job, thank you, after 5min i accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Because it has a property of `display: table-cell` which will force it to behave like a table.

You can just add `display: block` in your current code.

Alternatively, replace the code with a single `display: none` will do the trick.

Or, with a rather weird styling, see below.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

section {
  display: table-cell;
}

aside {
  display: table-cell;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;

  /*__transition*/
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .25s;
}

footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: table-row;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  main {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

  section {
    width: 100%;
  }

  aside {    
    display: none;
    
    /* OR */
    
    display: table-cell;
    border: none;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    
    /* OR */
    
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>HEADER</header>
      <main>
        <section>SECTION</section>
        <aside>ASIDE</aside>
      </main>
      <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do you want the transition to work exactly? Mind elaborate more in your question?

Comment: @RamzanChasygov see my updated answer to check if it meets the transition thingy

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `display: table` to make the layout.

Tables have their own way to calculating their width, so setting a width doesn't mean that it will be exactly that.

Try using `display: none` instead

Comment: Why do you want to do a transition on a @media query? It's unnecessary as the users usually don't resize their screen. And on mobile phones, there is already an animation of rotating the screen.

Comment: it wants client

Comment: Well, so you shouldn't use `display: table` for layouts. Try using `display: flex`. Even though I recommend you to put a sense in your client :P